# If Redux `connect` relies on reference comparisons, why are only serializable values allowed as payload?

Tags: reactjs, redux

The Redux [documentation](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions) states as a rule that we should avoid non-serializable values in actions, to ensure "that the UI will update as expected".

But in the [Performance FAQ](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/faq/Performance.md) we read:

> In addition, deep cloning state creates new references for every field. Since the React-Redux `connect` function relies on reference comparisons to determine if data has changed, this means that UI components will be forced to re-render unnecessarily even though the other data hasn't meaningfully changed.

I'm now insecure how this works.

If a changed reference is the deciding factor that something changed and the component has to be rerendered, why can't we use e.g. functions in action payloads?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the actual risks of storing non-serializable data items in Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205930/what-are-the-actual-risks-of-storing-non-serializable-data-items-in-redux-store)

Comment: The documentation says `This ensures that capabilities such as debugging via the Redux DevTools will work`, the UI updating as expected is just another aspect. `Capabilities` also includes things like persisting the state, which doesn't work with functions.